# What If my Russian visa got refused?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, russia

If my Russian visa got refused, can I apply again and what are my chances to get it?

I think my documents might not be 100% correct, so i may get refused based on incomplete documents.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please clarify why you think your visa is going to be refused and ask a more precise question.

Comment: i mean if i got refused for incomplete documents

Comment: If you have incomplete documents, they wouldn't be accepted, no visa application would happen.